# command prompt tutorials on linux

Tags: c++, linux

I have a program I am trying to port to linux.

The program is a command prompt program that displays memory on screen, you can move around the memory using the arrow keys.

Im new to linux and don't really understand how the terminal works.

What Im looking for is some good tutorials or a chapter in a book to teach me hoe to write linux programs using the terminal the same way I would use command prompt in windows.

I want to know things like changing background and text colours, clearing the screen, being able to move up and down the lines of text and how to detect keyboard input. Basically how to create a user interface using the linux terminal.

I am using centos and g++ if that makes a difference.

Comment: You may want to look into the [Curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) library.

Comment: Three hundred million duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you need [ncurses](http://www.bigwebmaster.com/General/Howtos/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 2):

Something like `htop`? You should have a look on [ncruses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).